# What are ways to send data using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I need to send HTTP POST data to a webpage. My host is missing some extensions (I'm not sure which ones). I tried cURL and fopen, neither of them work.

What are other ways to send data?

Edit: By the way, I can send $_GET data as well. So as long as I can open a url (eg. file_get_contents), it's works.

Comment: You should create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo();` in it and nothing else. That will tell you what you are dealing with and what extensions you can use.

Comment: If those two don't work, assume that your host explicitly disabled access to other resources. `fopen` is a standard PHP function and has to be disabled manually by an administrator. They aren't extensions.

Comment: I am using fopen to open a remote URL. Is that enabled by default?
I'll try the phpinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the very powerful [PHP stream functions](http://us.php.net/stream).

However, if the file/stream and cURL functions are disabled - then make them on the frontend using AJAX requests. [jQuery](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) [is good at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) as long as the data isn't sensitive.

I built an entire [blog system](http://xeoncross.github.com/MicroStream/) using just jQuery JSONP requests on the frontend since I wanted to move the load to the user instead of my server.

Answer (score 0):

This may work. The context is not really needed, but allows you to set custom timeout and user-agent.

```
/* Set up array with options for the context used by file_get_contents(). */
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'timeout' => 4,
    'header'  => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                 "User-Agent: Some UA\r\n"
  )
);

/* Create context. */
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

/* Make the request */
$response = @file_get_contents('http://example.com/?foo=bar', null, $context);

if($response === false) {
  /* Could not make request. */
}
```

You can use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build your query string from an array.